# Proof for a certain definite integral.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

In one of our lectures, we were finding the general rule for the integration of monomials ($\int_a^b  x^n dx$) and we assumed the rule that $\int_0^1  x^n dx=\frac{1}{n+1} $ to  find $\int_a^b  x^n dx$. What is the proof for $\int_0^1  x^n dx=\frac{1}{n+1} $?

Note: We have covered the algebra of integrals, properties of integration, and the Riemann conditions for integrability and for the value of an integral.

Comment: Don't you know how to compute definite integrals?

Comment: Must $n$ be an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a partition of $[0,1]$, for example $x_k=\frac{k}{N}$, with $k=0,\dots,N$. Then the area under the graph of $x^n$ between $0$ and $1$ can be approximated by rectangles as
$$\int_0^1 x^n dx \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N} \left(\frac{k}{N}\right)^n.$$
Here, $\frac{1}{N}$ is the base of each rectangle and $\left(\frac{k}{N}\right)^n$ the height of the $k$-th rectangle, then we sum up.

Let us look at the sum:
$$S=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N} \left(\frac{k}{N}\right)^n.$$
We can simplify $S$ as
$$S=\frac{1}{N^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^N k^n.$$

Observe that we have a quotient of sequences $a_N=\sum_{k=1}^N k^n$ and $b_N=N^{n+1}$, $N\geq 1$ where $b_N$ is strictly increasing and divergent, then we can apply the following theorem, [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), to compute the limit when $N\to \infty$.

$$\int_0^1 x^ndx=\lim_N \frac{a_N}{b_N}=\lim_N \frac{a_{N+1}-a_{N}}{b_{N+1}-b_{N}}=\lim_N \frac{(N+1)^n}{(N+1)^{n+1}-N^{n+1}}.$$

Now you can divide by $(N+1)^n$ the numerator and denominator to obtain
$$\lim_N \frac{(N+1)^n}{(N+1)^{n+1}-N^{n+1}} = \lim_N \frac{1}{N+1-\left(\frac{N}{N+1}\right)^{n}N } = \lim_N \frac{1}{1+N\left[1-\left(1+\frac{1}{N}\right)^{-n}\right]}.$$

Now observe that
$$\lim_N N\left[1-\left(1+\frac{1}{N}\right)^{-n}\right]= \lim_N \frac{1/N}{1-\left(1+\frac{1}{N}\right)^{-n}}=n,$$
where in the last step you may use L'Hôpital's rule to obtain the limit.

As a result,
$$\int_0^1 x^ndx = \frac{1}{1+n}.$$